# Javascript how to do substring global replacement with specific rule applied

Tags: javascript, string

I want a function which can replace substring in a big string with specific rule.

for example, I want every digit for `pageX` in the string increase by 10.

```
function replace(str, increment){}
```

do`replace("pageX : 100, pageY: 200,......pageX : 120...", 10)`

will get `"pageX : 110, pageY: 200,......pageX : 130..."`

I know that like `string.replace(/pageX :/g,someStr)` can do `replaceAll`, but no rule can be applied.
How can I get that?

Comment: Why is `200` not increased (typo?)? You have to write your own logic for that, there is nothing built-in that can do that. That is: extract the numbers, increase them, put them back.

Comment: Have a look at [Javascript string replace with calculations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843455/javascript-string-replace-with-calculations) for some inspiration.

Comment: @Felix Kling `200` is for `pageY`..there's a small different

Comment: Then I would change the sentence *"I want every digit in the string increase by 10"* to make this clearer. Otherwise everyone will think you want to change very number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) function callback:

```
var string = "pageX : 100, pageY: 200,......pageX : 120...";
string = string.replace(/(\d+)/g, function(match, contents) {
    return (+contents + 10);
});
console.log(string);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ytptN/

Answer (score 0):

Use [Regexp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) with `\d+` pattern to match all numbers and use [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) ability to generate replacement with function call. Multiply (or otherwise) modify matched numbers there and put them back.